# visual studio 2017 install break : it not get start

Tags: installation, visual-studio-2017

- I use the permission of Administrator to install vs_enterprise.exe.
  But the install package don't work at all.
- OS: win10 professional
- The install log in appdata/local/temp/ is as follow:

**dd_bootstrapper_20170313103210:**

Beginning of the log. Start Time: 13/03/2017 10:32:10  
VisualStudio Bootstrapper:13/03/2017 10:32:10: Current Optin root path does not
   exists  
VisualStudio Bootstrapper:13/03/2017 10:32:11: Commandline
   arguments =

**dd_vs_enterprise_decompression_log.txt**:

[3/13/2017, 10:32:4] === Logging started: 2017/03/13 10:32:04 === 
[3/13/2017, 10:32:4] Executable: D:\vs2017\vs_enterprise.exe
   v15.0.26206.0  
[3/13/2017, 10:32:4] --- logging level: standard ---
    
[3/13/2017, 10:32:4] Directory
   'C:\Users\gary\AppData\Local\Temp\b012f31d56525c685e\' has been
   selected for file extraction  
[3/13/2017, 10:32:4] Extracting files
   to: C:\Users\gary\AppData\Local\Temp\b012f31d56525c685e\  
[3/13/2017,
   10:32:5] Extraction took 484 milliseconds  
[3/13/2017, 10:32:5]
   Executing extracted package:
   'vs_bootstrapper_d15\vs_setup_bootstrapper.exe ' with commandline ' '
    
[3/13/2017, 10:32:11] The entire Box execution exiting with result
   code: 0x0  
[3/13/2017, 10:32:11] Launched extracted application
   exiting with result code: 0xc000000d  
[3/13/2017, 10:32:11] ===
   Logging stopped: 2017/03/13 10:32:11 ===

Thank You~

Answer (score 11):

I was having this exact problem, thought it was a services thing. The installer would start if I ran it as soon as Windows booted; if I waited, it didn't.

Turns out it was RivaTunerStatistics server that was running for my gaming overlays. Closed it, and voila, working again. Tried multiple times to confirm.

Comment: Thanks so much for this, I would have never guessed that it was RTSS.

Comment: Thank you for the tip, in my case it was MSI Afterburner, RTSS wasn't even running.

Comment: @WillemdeKok MSI Afterburner also installs and runs RTSS, If you have it in single icon mode you wont see RTSS in your system tray, even if you do MSI Aterburner will auto restart it. Closing MSI Afterburner will close both, and setting the application detection to non in RTSS will allow it to run.

Comment: Oh man. I was stumped trying to solve this. Gamer-programmer problems.

Answer (score 5):

I had a similar issue, my Visual Studio Professional 2017 installer was closing before the installation starts. I solve the issue by following these steps:

1 - Open the prompt(CMD) with administration rights

2 - Check if you have the "InstallCleanup.exe" file inside the folder "%programfiles(x86)%\Microsoft Visual Studio\Installer\resources\app\layout\". If the file is there then go to step 7

3 - Manually delete the "%programfiles(x86)%\Microsoft Visual Studio\Installer” folder

4 - Relaunch the newly downloaded visual studio installer

5 - Allow the first step to install the installer

6 - Once the installer comes up and you can see workload choices (.net desktop and the like), close it

7 - inside CMD navigate to the folder "%programfiles(x86)%\Microsoft Visual Studio\Installer\resources\app\layout\"

3 - run this command: "InstallCleanup.exe -full"

4 - that's it. Just run the installer again.

It worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same Problem on two different Pc's (both win10) and the only thing that worked for me, was reinstalling Windows's and rerun the visual studio installer. I know, that's not a good, fast or easy solution, but it works.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue with the VS 2017 installer (similar error message), and I was finally able to resolve my problem after 4 days of troubleshooting with Microsoft Support. I'm developing on a Dell laptop and the support technician believes one of the Dell services was causing issues with the winmgmt service.

Below is a command that failed to run during troubleshooting. After making sure we had an OS restore point saved, we issued the winmgmt /resetRepository command. After that, the VS 2017 Pro installer was able to execute without error.

Here are the exact steps taken by Microsoft Support:

Step 1: Create a Windows system restore point.

Step 2: From the command prompt with administrative rights or elevated privileges, execute the following command: net stop winmgmt

Step 3: Open a Windows Explorer and locate the path to C:\windows\system32\WBEM\ folder and rename the Repository folder to something else like RepositoryOLD (right click and choose 'Rename Folder').

Step 4: restart the computer

Step 5: From the command prompt with administrative rights or elevated privileges, execute the following command: net stop winmgmt

```
C:\>net stop winmgmt
The Windows Management Instrumentation service is stopping.
The Windows Management Instrumentation service could not be stopped.
```

Step 6: From the command prompt with administrative rights or elevated privileges, execute the following steps and execute the following this: winmgmt /resetRepository

```
C:\>winmgmt /resetRepository
WMI repository has been reset
```

Step 7: restart the computer.

Hope this helps someone else.

Comment: didn't help :( any other options to try?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem but it was solved by the answer @Ben Logan gave (Closing RivaTunerStatistics).

Comment: This should be a comment on the answer you are referencing.

Comment: I don't seem to be able to do that, you must have 50 points or something for that. Wanted to point the answer out so i thought maybe if i post an answer it will help. My bad if this is not the right way to do that and feel free to delete my answer!

Comment: Typically not the correct way. But whatever, you're just tryin' to help.

Answer (score 1):

After trying all the suggested answers here (using VS 2017), I followed the instructions on [the official Microsoft docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/troubleshooting-installation-issues) which worked for me. In summary:

1. Close the Visual Studio Installer.
2. Delete the Visual Studio Installer directory. Typically, the directory is `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Installer`.
3. Run the Visual Studio Installer bootstrapper. You may find the bootstrapper in your Downloads folder with a file name that follows a `vs_[Visual Studio edition]__*.exe` pattern. If you don't find that application, you can download the bootstrapper by going to the [Visual Studio downloads](https://www.visualstudio.com/downloads/) page and clicking **Download** for your edition of Visual Studio. Run the executable to reset your installation metadata.
4. Try to install or update Visual Studio again. If the Installer continues to fail, go to the next step.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone still having this problem:

One of my co-workers encountered the same problem. We spent 4 hours searching for solutions, uninstalling VS and other software that we thought might be the culprit.

In the end, [THIS LINK](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/224084/installer-wont-show-up-when-i-have-node-options-va.html) helped us figure it out. The problem is somehow explained there and is linked to `NODE_OPTIONS variable`. If you have that variable set, **remove** it then **restart** your computer. This solved his problem.

*Configuration:
Widows 10, Visual Studio 2017 Enterprise.*

I hope this helps you

Answer (score 0):

Copy vs_enterprise.exe to a USB and run. It will work.

Answer (score 0):

try to run this file using console
example: `c:/vs_community__556869458.1519050247.exe`