# Visual studio 2017 installer won't run after extracting

Tags: visual-studio, installation, visual-studio-2017, temp

visual studio 2017 community.exe won't run after extracting to the temp.

OS: windows 10 x64bit

Setup : community version

in the temp folder bootstrapper log says,

**Beginning of the log. Start Time: 3/26/2017 1:14:54 AM
VisualStudio Bootstrapper:3/26/2017 1:14:54 AM: Current Optin root path does not exists

VisualStudio Bootstrapper:3/26/2017 1:14:55 AM: Commandline arguments =**

and the dd_vs_community_decompression_log says
**[3/26/2017, 11:17:47] === Logging started: 2017/03/26 11:17:47 ===

[3/26/2017, 11:17:47] Executable: C:\Users\Sameera\Downloads\Programs\vs_community.exe v15.0.26228.0

[3/26/2017, 11:17:47] --- logging level: standard ---

[3/26/2017, 11:17:47] Directory 
'C:\Users\Sameera\AppData\Local\Temp\4ceac4b7b9cd9fdf2489526c66\' has been selected for file extraction

[3/26/2017, 11:17:48] Extracting files to: C:\Users\Sameera\AppData\Local\Temp\4ceac4b7b9cd9fdf2489526c66\

[3/26/2017, 11:17:48] Extraction took 360 milliseconds

[3/26/2017, 11:17:48] Executing extracted package: 'vs_bootstrapper_d15\vs_setup_bootstrapper.exe ' with commandline ' '

[3/26/2017, 11:18:10] The entire Box execution exiting with result code: 0x0

[3/26/2017, 11:18:10] Launched extracted application exiting with result code: 0xc000000d

[3/26/2017, 11:18:10] === Logging stopped: 2017/03/26 11:18:10 ===**

can't find proper solution..

Comment: You are not alone. Someone else posted a similar thread.
[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42755939/visual-studio-2017-install-break-it-not-get-start/43051252#43051252](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42755939/visual-studio-2017-install-break-it-not-get-start/43051252#43051252)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I was able to resolve my problem after 4 days of troubleshooting with Microsoft support. I'm developing on a Dell laptop and the support technician believes one of the Dell services was causing issues with the winmgmt service.

Below is a command that failed to run. Then after making sure we had an OS restore point saved, we issued the /resetRepository command. After that, the VS 2017 Pro installer was able to execute without error.

EDIT: Adding the exact steps and code sample below:

Step 1: Create a Windows system restore point.

Step 2: From the command prompt with administrative rights or elevated privileges, execute the following command: net stop winmgmt

Step 3: Open a Windows Explorer and locate the path to C:\windows\system32\WBEM\ folder and rename the Repository folder to something else like RepositoryOLD (right click and choose 'Rename Folder').

Step 4: restart the computer

Step 5: From the command prompt with administrative rights or elevated privileges, execute the following command: net stop winmgmt

```
C:\>net stop winmgmt
The Windows Management Instrumentation service is stopping.
The Windows Management Instrumentation service could not be stopped.
```

Step 6: From the command prompt with administrative rights or elevated privileges, execute the following command: winmgmt /resetRepository

```
C:\>winmgmt /resetRepository
WMI repository has been reset
```

Step 7: restart the computer.

Hope this helps anyone with a similar Visual Studio 2017 installer issue.

Comment: i also use Dell laptop. but this didn't works for me.. :(

Comment: Sameera, I updated my post above with the exact steps Microsoft support took to resolve my issue.

Comment: Thank you very much  SHClark.. :)

Comment: While this solution would probably work in many cases, mine was some component corrupted during the installation of a Cisco VPN client. This made it so my existing instances of VS 2015 and 2017 would not open, nor would the installer launch after having unzipped the bootstrapper for 2017. 
I ended up completely uninstalling every instance, reinstalling all Visual C++ libs from 2008 to 2017 (after seeing a missing dll error at one point) and after still not working, completely deleting the entire VisualStudio folder from the registry 
 > `HKEY_CURRENT_USER/Software/VisualStudio`

Answer (score 16):

I had this problem too. SHClark's answer didn't work for me. I figured out myself what was causing the problem on my computer: Mirekusoft Install Monitor. I disabled both its services and that solved the problem. (I guess that's not an extremely likely program for someone to have running, but it could be a problem common to install monitors in general?)

I also heard from someone on the Visual Studio Community forum that RivaTunerStatistics (used for gaming) can cause this problem too.

Comment: For future Searchers, Set Application detection level to "none" or just stop RivaTuner and retry the installer.  
  
I have but one vote to give... Thank you :-) RivaTuner Statistics was the issue for me. Dunno why. Random stab in the dark? Its used to overlay things like an FPS count. Killed RivaTuner Statistics and I was able to launch.  
  
Just to narrow it down, I closed the installer and restarted RivaTuner Statistics and indeed the issue returned. Disabling the overlay options didn't let the installer launch but setting the application detection to none (off) did the trick.

Comment: wow it was RivaTuner that was causing the problems...I would have never guessed that.

Comment: +1 It was RivaTuner. Spent at least 6 hours over 4 days on this. I would really like to understand how RivaTuner, which as far as I know mucks with the DX pipeline, would affect the VS installer.

Comment: Thankfully I found this reasonably quickly, but I would have spent ages otherwise. I would have never guessed RivaTuner. Thanks!

Comment: I used [nifsoft's appcrash program](https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/app_crash_view.html) to detect that the `vs_setup_bootstrapper.exe` had an access violation in d3d9.dll. After some more googling I found someone mention that rivatuner can lock access to d3d9 and cause issues. After stopping MSI afterburner and uninstalling rivatuner and restarting, the launcher finally came up.

Answer (score 11):

One of my co-workers encountered the same problem. We spent 4 hours searching for solutions, uninstalling VS and other software that we thought might be the culprit.

In the end, [THIS LINK](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/224084/installer-wont-show-up-when-i-have-node-options-va.html) helped us figure it out. The problem is somehow explained there and is linked to `NODE_OPTIONS variable`. If you have that variable set, **remove** it then **restart** your computer. This solved his problem.

*Configuration:
Widows 10, Visual Studio 2017 Enterprise.*

I hope this helps you

Comment: You saved me. I spent almost a day and at least 4 hours with online Microsoft support chat, and in the end it was just this variable. Google Play Music Player stopped here too for the same reason, after remove the variable everything worked.

Comment: You are a live saver :). I have been struggling with this install issue for last few days and deleting the NODE_OPTIONS environment variable finally displays the installer workloads screen. Thanks you.

Comment: Amazing, after some hours of searching the web, this was the solution! Thank you.

Comment: You are a lifesaver. Thank you! I spent several hours trying all the suggestions from the net. I didn't even have to restart the computer. Once I removed it from my environmental variables, it immediately worked.

Comment: Saved me :) Would've never guessed this. I had added this in because I was getting Out of memory errors during gulp build.

Comment: Got the same problem and found the solution before finding this :/ so I lost some time. Unfortunately I couldn't find any error codes until I found it is related to node.dll.

Answer (score 4):

Copy vs_community.exe to a USB and run. It will work.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same (or similar) problem.  I couldn't update VS2017, either from within the program or by trying to run the installer.
The web page at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/troubleshooting-installation-issues had instructions that resolved the problem.  For me, deleting the 'Installer' directory and then retrying the installation resolved the problem.

Comment: I didn't even have to delete the folder. Just downloading the VS installer made Visual Studio Installer work again.

Answer (score 1):

Try deleting this folder `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\`.
Restart the install.

Comment: After retrying several times, and trying to run vs_installer.exe manually (it does not appear) - I grabbed a copy of the vs_bootstrapper_d15 folder from 'temp', deleted VS folder as recommended, then ran vs_setup_bootstrapper.exe with success.

Answer (score 1):

**Note for others** with installer problems for Visual Studio 2017/2019/vNext

Before messing with your system **FIRST TRY CLOSING EVERY OTHER PROGRAM**.

Sounds silly, i know! But I almost missed inhahe's answer mentioning that RivaTuner could cause problems. Closing that caused it to start working *instantly*.

**TL;DR**: Close all other programs like you always ignore in installation instructions :)

Comment: Ahh yes, of course it's RivaTuner. You just saved me hours of head scratching

Answer (score 1):

Try to stop MSI AfterBurner. Worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

It's the same answer as in question [visual studio 2017 install break : it not get start](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42755939/visual-studio-2017-install-break-it-not-get-start/43051252#43051252) just in case you don't observe the other question.

I had the same Problem on two different Pc's (both win10) and the only thing that worked for me, was reinstalling Windows's and rerun the visual studio installer. I know, that's not a good, fast or easy solution, but it works.

Answer (score 0):

I have been having this issue all day and MS support were not able to help. To solve my issue, I updated my video driver to the latest version (I was intentionally using an old driver as the new versions don't support my monitor resolution). The visual studio installer must use a GUI tech not supported by my older card and just fails before the installer GUI loads. The same issue happened with the older, offline installers for older versions such as VS2013.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem also (with a Dell labtop) and SHClark's didn't work for me.
Here is what I did:

I used the command line to create a local cache of the files you need to complete an offline install

`[ctrl] [shift] [enter]` for the cmd prompt to run as admin

1) typed

```
d:\vs_community.exe --layout h:\vs2017layout --add Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.NativeDesktop --includeRecommended --lang en-US
```

once it was done downloading to `h:\vs2017layout`,

2)
opened `h:\vs2017layout\vs_setup.exe`
finally got it to open after extracting but ran into this error:

```
The name of the file cannot be resolved by the system
```

so I created a link for the `c:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Visual Studio` folder using the following command at windows cmd promt:

```
mklink /D "C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\VisualStudio" "g:\ProgramData\Microsoft\VisualStudio"
```

It worked after that. Not sure if the second error was related to the first. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, the fix is: go to reigonal settings from control panel, then on the administrative tab select (or if selected reselect) current language for non-unicode programs. than try again.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Here is my solution:

1. right click vs installer, extract with winrar.
2. go to extracted folder.
3. run: `vs_setup_bootstrapper.exe`

This worked for me :)

[image]

Comment: another solution : I reinstall windows in DELL vostro but same problem. I changed system locale to another and I can install visual studio and other applications. I think the problem is not about visual studio. The problem caused something else. Also you can copy / paste the installer to usb drive and run it. It's very strange

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and the problem was my user name containing both space and a non ascii character (Olcay Ertaş). I have moved the installer to my root folder and it worked. This is probably the reason why @oğuzhan-türk's solution is also working.

Answer (score 0):

If you have Win8 you needed to update your system to 8.1 ver. and restart your computer.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem. Turned out there was an old, failed installation on the drive. I had to go to Control Panel->Add/Remove Programs and remove Visual Studio Install Tool. After that the installer worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

Faced the same problem with Visual Studio 2019, but I think version doesn't matter here. This thread helped me: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/326811/vs-community-installer-not-running-working.html.
The reason was in somehow corrupted .NET files.

Actions applied:

- deleted all apps with "Microsoft .NET" in name using https://support.microsoft.com/ru-ru/help/17588/windows-fix-problems-that-block-programs-being-installed-or-removed
- downloaded and installed latest version of .NET Framework Runtime (not .NET Core Runtime) from https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download, in my case it was version 4.8
- restarted PC

This helped me.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing worked for me here however i was able to find out that there was an error with the main.js file that he couldn't find the temp folder. so i looked up the environment variables and indeed for my current user TEMP was not set resp. empty. i copied the default temp value(%SystemRoot%\TEMP) for all users to my current user TEMP variable and afterwards everything worked

Answer (score 0):

I have lost a lot of time to solve it. By me, it was an error in machine.config, which I made 2 weeks ago. I have found it only because I have tried to uninstall the JetBrains too. And there was an error too , but with a log, where I could see it.

Answer (score 0):

After search during days and didn't work...
I tried uninstall all .NET frameworks and it works!

Answer (score 0):

I have tried all the answers provided so far and none of them worked for me.
What I did after 2 days of searching for issues online and google-ing, as I have started Windows Event Viewer and googled the error that was logged in the Event Viewer at the time of Bootstrapper crash.

The problem was somewhat similar to @inhanes problem above. It turned out to be the Fresco Logic Driver installation that was causing the issue. I have deleted the driver (add or remove programs -> uninstall) and the damn thing worked.
By the way, this driver is written for USB3.0->HDMI converter.

Anyway, guys and girls: Event Viewer which is a built-in Windows logger can be helpful. :) Now I can just leave in peace and develop my stuff.