# Visual Studio 2015 Setup crashing

Tags: visual-studio-2015, installation, crash

today I wanted to install Visual Studio (Visual Studio 2015 Community) again, but every time I try to start the setup the Application crashes like so:

1. I try to execute the .exe I downloaded
2. A window pops up saying that it is extraction files.
3. I am prompted to press "Continue" assuming that I accept the terms of service etc.
4. Application Crashes.

What I've done so far:

1. Check the log files that are being generated, with little success so far.
   The only thing that catches the eye is an error saying "read ENOTCONN" is a Problem. 
   When trying to google that specific error I didn't find anything known and related to a Visual Studio Installation.
2. Repair vc redistributable. Didn't do anything.
3. Google like a madman, trying to find an answer.

My Log files:

`dd_vs_community__993787685.1494957250 (2)_decompression_log` [(pastebin)](https://pastebin.com/WN1nbfgV)

```
[5/21/2017, 20:27:3] === Logging started: 2017/05/21 20:27:03 ===
[5/21/2017, 20:27:3] Executable: C:\Users\Jörn\Desktop\vs_community__993787685.1494957250 (2).exe v15.0.26430.6
[5/21/2017, 20:27:3] --- logging level: standard ---
[5/21/2017, 20:27:3] Directory 'C:\Users\JRN~1\AppData\Local\Temp\49a16bc471d38c0276dd\' has been selected for file extraction
[5/21/2017, 20:27:3] Extracting files to: C:\Users\JRN~1\AppData\Local\Temp\49a16bc471d38c0276dd\
[5/21/2017, 20:27:3] Extraction took 234 milliseconds
[5/21/2017, 20:27:3] Executing extracted package: 'vs_bootstrapper_d15\vs_setup_bootstrapper.exe ' with commandline ' '
[5/21/2017, 20:27:6] The entire Box execution exiting with result code: 0x0
[5/21/2017, 20:27:6] Launched extracted application exiting with result code: 0x0
[5/21/2017, 20:27:6] === Logging stopped: 2017/05/21 20:27:06 ===
```

`ErrorInfo.a7c369d2ecee6c3e37938311c705ae98` [(pastebin)](https://pastebin.com/TqHMn9Xu)

```
ErrorTypeText=Error
ErrorDescription=read ENOTCONN
ErrorNumber=0
SourceFile=node
PackageVersion=v6.3.0
Line=1008
Character=11
StackTrace=ms-appx://util.js:0:0           exports._errnoException
           ms-appx://node@v6.3.0:416:21           net.js.Socket._read
           ms-appx://node@v6.3.0:349:10           _stream_readable.js.Socket.Readable.read
           ms-appx://node@v6.3.0:299:43           net.js.Socket.read
           ms-appx://node@v6.3.0:179:12           net.js.Socket.constructor
           ms-appx://node@v6.3.0:232:11           internal\child_process.js.createSocket
           ms-appx://node@v6.3.0:318:22           internal\child_process.js.
           ms-appx://UNKNOWN@undefined:-1:-1           native.Array.forEach
           ms-appx://node@v6.3.0:307:9           internal\child_process.js.ChildProcess.spawn
           ms-appx://node@v6.3.0:384:9           child_process.js.exports.spawn
StackTraceHash=a7c369d2ecee6c3e37938311c705ae98
ErrorContext=ElectronMain
CodeBranch=update2
```

If there is need for any more information that I've not yet provided I would be more than happy to provide it.

Any help will be very much appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please open task manager and end all VS installer tasks, make sure windows update is up-to-date, temporarily disable any antivirus software, clean up %temp% folder and re-run the installer as administrator. If this issue persists, it looks like some other software caused by this issue, please check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43025670/visual-studio-2017-installer-wont-run-after-extracting?noredirect=1&lq=1 to check if you installed their software or not.

Comment: Thank you so much. The Windows update part worked wonders! Apparently Windows had huge problems getting the new Updates on my PC for whatever reason, took ages but now it's done

Comment: Hi Jörn Lüerßen, I'm so glad to hear that your issue is solved and I added a reply with this solution, could you please mark it as answer when you have free time? It will help other community members to easier search this solution, thanks.

Comment: Please mark the helpful answer as accepted if it solved your question :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually, before we try to install the VS and there have some installation tips that can help us to avoid the unnecessary issues, please have a look at the following:

1. Make sure windows update is up-to-date
2. Temporarily disable antivirus software
3. Clean up the %temp% folder
4. Run the installer as administrator