# Visual Studio setup doesn't start

Tags: visual-studio, failed-installation

I have just downloaded the Visual Studio Community setup, run it and it doesn't go further than administrator confirmation, then it just shuts down. It worked for me before on Windows 8.1 (now I am on Windows 10 x64).

Comment: Do you have any error message?

Comment: No error messages, it just doesn't open. If You want to I can give a log, but I don't know where it is.

Comment: There is actually a small window, that shows "preparing files" it is saving some stuff in the temp folder. Crashes at "vs_setup_boostrapper.json".

Comment: And I found the log file: https://pastebin.com/4jj2nJAP

Comment: It seems that `vs_bootstrapper_d15\vs_setup_bootstrapper.exe` ended with an error code. But that doesn't tell much.

Comment: There is the log file for the bootstrapper: https://pastebin.com/eeSCCgn5

Comment: [Looks an awful lot like your problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43025670/visual-studio-2017-installer-wont-run-after-extracting). The return code is different (he got 0xD while you have 0x5) But it could be worth a shot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43025670/visual-studio-2017-installer-wont-run-after-extracting) guide solved my problem, Visual Studio installed without any problems.