# Unable to start the Visual Studio 2017 installer on Windows Server 2012 R2

Tags: visual-studio, installation, visual-studio-2017, windows-server-2012-r2

Unable to start the VS2017 installer on my Windows Server 2012, after the unpacking it just silently stops working. I found [similar issue here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43025670/visual-studio-2017-installer-wont-run-after-extracting) and [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4015967/troubleshooting-visual-studio-2017-installation-and-upgrade-failures) but nothing helped:

- Repository reset
- RivaTunerStatistics monitor
- Mirekusoft Install monitor
- Remove installer data (ProgramData/Microsoft/VisualStudio/Packages)

Here is the error after I'm starting the installer which was downloaded via MSDN subscriptions website (vs 2017 ver 15.2)

```
Fault bucket , type 0
Event Name: VisualStudioNonFatalErrors2
Response: Not available
Cab Id: 0

Problem signature:
P1: vs_setup_bootstrapper
P2: 15.0.346.44760
P3: vs.setup.bootstrapper.error
P4: System.Management.ManagementException
P5: Microsoft.VisualStudio.Telemetry.Net35
P6: n/a
P7: 5002
P8: -2146233087
P9: unknown
P10: unknown

Attached files:
C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Local\Temp\2\dd_bootstrapper_20170808055355.log
C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Local\Temp\2\VSFaultInfo\170808_055356_3813308\ErrorInformation.txt

These files may be available here:


Analysis symbol: 
Rechecking for solution: 0
Report Id: f6b0cb3c-7bfd-11e7-81ed-000d3a70e014
Report Status: 262144
Hashed bucket:
```

The log is here:

```
Beginning of the log. Start Time: 8/8/2017 5:53:55 AM
VisualStudio Bootstrapper:8/8/2017 5:53:55 AM: Current Optin root path does not exists
VisualStudio Bootstrapper:8/8/2017 5:53:55 AM: Caught Exception: Type = ManagementException, Message = Invalid namespace , StackTrace =    at System.Management.ThreadDispatch.Start()
   at System.Management.ManagementScope.Initialize()
   at System.Management.ManagementObject.Initialize(Boolean getObject)
   at System.Management.ManagementObject.Get()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Setup.Bootstrapper.Utilities.GetParentProcess(ILogger logger, Boolean throwOnComException)
VisualStudio Bootstrapper:8/8/2017 5:53:55 AM: Invalid namespace 
VisualStudio Bootstrapper:8/8/2017 5:53:55 AM: Caught Exception: Type = ManagementException, Message = Invalid namespace , StackTrace =    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Setup.Bootstrapper.Utilities.GetParentProcess(ILogger logger, Boolean throwOnComException)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Setup.Bootstrapper.Program.Parse(String[] args, ILogger logger, String entryAssemblyProcessName, String entryAssemblyProcessFullName)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Setup.Bootstrapper.Program.Run(String[] args)
VisualStudio Bootstrapper:8/8/2017 5:53:55 AM: General Failure. Message:Invalid namespace  Callstack:    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Setup.Bootstrapper.Utilities.GetParentProcess(ILogger logger, Boolean throwOnComException)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Setup.Bootstrapper.Program.Parse(String[] args, ILogger logger, String entryAssemblyProcessName, String entryAssemblyProcessFullName)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Setup.Bootstrapper.Program.Run(String[] args) Inner Message: Internal Exception: 
VisualStudio Bootstrapper:8/8/2017 5:53:55 AM: Watson: Sending Watson Bucket with:
VisualStudio Bootstrapper:8/8/2017 5:53:55 AM: Watson: P1  = vs_setup_bootstrapper
VisualStudio Bootstrapper:8/8/2017 5:53:55 AM: Watson: P2  = 15.0.346.44760
VisualStudio Bootstrapper:8/8/2017 5:53:55 AM: Watson: P3  = 
VisualStudio Bootstrapper:8/8/2017 5:53:55 AM: Watson: P4  = 
VisualStudio Bootstrapper:8/8/2017 5:53:55 AM: Watson: P5  = 
VisualStudio Bootstrapper:8/8/2017 5:53:55 AM: Watson: P6  = n/a
VisualStudio Bootstrapper:8/8/2017 5:53:55 AM: Watson: P7  = 5002
VisualStudio Bootstrapper:8/8/2017 5:53:55 AM: Watson: P8  = -2146233087
VisualStudio Bootstrapper:8/8/2017 5:53:55 AM: Watson: P9  = 
VisualStudio Bootstrapper:8/8/2017 5:53:55 AM: Watson: P10 = 
VisualStudio Bootstrapper:8/8/2017 5:53:55 AM: Watson: Including dmp file
VisualStudio Bootstrapper:8/8/2017 5:53:55 AM: Watson: Including Log : C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Local\Temp\2\dd_bootstrapper_20170808055355.log
```

And the error information is here:

```
Error Information
AppInsightsEvent Name = vs/setup/bootstrapper/error
          Description = ManagementException
     TelemetrySession = '1aa2e09c-bd07-4ad4-a079-b81fba910262' Started = True OptIn=True IsInitialized = False Cloned = False
             UTC time = 2017-08-08T05:53:55

 Exception:
 System.Management.ManagementException: Invalid namespace 
    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Setup.Bootstrapper.Utilities.GetParentProcess(ILogger logger, Boolean throwOnComException)
    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Setup.Bootstrapper.Program.Parse(String[] args, ILogger logger, String entryAssemblyProcessName, String entryAssemblyProcessFullName)
    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Setup.Bootstrapper.Program.Run(String[] args)
Telemetry Session Shared Properties:
   VS.Core.User.Location.GeoId = 244
   VS.Core.SkuName = VS Bootstrapper
   VS.Core.ExeName = vs_setup_bootstrapper
   VS.Core.User.IsOptedIn = True
   VS.Core.User.IsMicrosoftInternal = False
   VS.Core.User.Type = External
   VS.Core.MacAddressHash = 0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
   VS.Core.OS.Version = 6.3.9600.18505
   VS.Core.User.Id = 5b5929d6-eb59-4572-97b3-7fae79e3f23e
   VS.Core.Machine.Id = 4e52cd2f-6893-4e2a-adee-a52551ee689a
   VS.Core.User.IsMicrosoftInternalDeprecated = False
   VS.Core.ExeVersion = 15.0.346.44760
   VS.Core.BuildNumber = 346
   VS.Core.TelemetryApi.ProductVersion = 15.0.777-rtm6FAA2C78
Telemetry event 'vs/setup/bootstrapper/error' properties:
   [VS.Setup.Bootstrapper.ReturnCode] = '5002'
   [VS.Setup.Bootstrapper.ErrorType] = 'ManagementException'
   [VS.Setup.Bootstrapper.Error] = 'Invalid namespace '
   [VS.Fault.WatsonOptIn] = 'PropertyOptIn'
   [VS.Fault.Exception.ModuleVersion] = '15.0.777.28586'
   [VS.Fault.Exception.Offset] = '733'
   [VS.Fault.WatsonReportNumber] = '0'
Telemetry event 'vs/setup/bootstrapper/error' reserved properties:
   [DataModel.Severity] = '10'
   [DataModel.Source] = 'DataModelApi'
   [DataModel.EntityType] = 'Fault'
   [DataModel.EntitySchemaVersion] = '4'
   [DataModel.CorrelationId] = '85bbbcad-350f-4b65-a7be-7a23ccfebbc9'
   [DataModel.ProductName] = 'vs'
   [DataModel.FeatureName] = 'setup/bootstrapper'
   [DataModel.EntityName] = 'error'
   [DataModel.Fault.Exception.TypeString] = 'System.Management.ManagementException'
   [DataModel.Fault.Exception.Message] = 'Invalid namespace '
   [DataModel.Fault.Exception.StackTrace] = 'System.Management.ManagementException: Invalid namespace 
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Setup.Bootstrapper.Utilities.GetParentProcess(ILogger logger, Boolean throwOnComException)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Setup.Bootstrapper.Program.Parse(String[] args, ILogger logger, String entryAssemblyProcessName, String entryAssemblyProcessFullName)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Setup.Bootstrapper.Program.Run(String[] args)'
   [DataModel.Fault.Description] = 'ManagementException'
   [DataModel.Fault.BucketParam1] = 'vs_setup_bootstrapper'
   [DataModel.Fault.BucketParam2] = '15.0.346.44760'
   [DataModel.Fault.BucketParam3] = 'vs.setup.bootstrapper.error'
   [DataModel.Fault.BucketParam4] = 'System.Management.ManagementException'
   [DataModel.Fault.BucketParam5] = 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Telemetry.Net35'
   [DataModel.Fault.BucketParam6] = 'n/a'
   [DataModel.Fault.BucketParam7] = '5002'
   [DataModel.Fault.BucketParam8] = '-2146233087'
   [DataModel.Fault.BucketParam9] = ''
   [DataModel.Fault.BucketParam10] = ''
   [DataModel.Fault.IsSampled] = 'True'

   CallStack Hash:5ced4440

   Added File C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Local\Temp\2\dd_bootstrapper_20170808055355.log
```

Update 3 of VS2017 has been released, and this time I was able to start the installer. Unfortuantely I got another error:

[image]

How can I fix that?

Comment: Hi Alexey, Please make sure you already installed Update 2919355 and all pending patches also installed, meanwhile the VS 2017 support on the Essentials, Standard and Datacenter versions. Refer to the error message, please check this blog: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vsnetsetup/2017/04/03/vs-2017-invalid-classsystem-management-managementexception-throwwithextendedinfomanagementstatus-errorcode/, go to Control Panel and if there has Visual Studio 2017, right click it to uninstall it, delete the folder: %ProgramFiles(x86)%\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\versioname, re-run the installer.

Comment: does your issue is solved or not? If not, please share your current condition and it will help us to analysis, thanks.

Comment: @Sara-MSFT the issue is still there. It's cloud based win server 2012 R2 with latest updates installed. VS 2017 is not on my list of installed programs and I also checked manually installation folders for the corrupted installer - no luck, no files. I didn't try this steps yet, going to give it a short asap: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vsnetsetup/2017/04/03/vs-2017-invalid-classsystem-management-managementexception-throwwithextendedinfomanagementstatus-errorcode/

Comment: Ah, these steps are the basically renaming `Repository`. I did it. No help. @Sara-MSFT

Comment: Hi Alexey, I need your help to collect the VS installation logs. Please use http://aka.ms/vscollect to gather the installation logs and find vslogs.zip under the %temp% folder, then upload the file to Onedrive and share the link here.