# Visual Studio 2017 Community .Exe File Shuts Down After Extracting Files, And Doesn't Start Setup.

Tags: visual-studio-2017, failed-installation

When I run my virtual studio 2017 community .exe file it extracts files into C:\DOCUME~1\mbryant\LOCALS~1\Temp\, but when it's done extracting it completely shuts down, and doesn't start the setup. *I have also already tried all answers in [Visual studio 2017 installer won't run after extracting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43025670/visual-studio-2017-installer-wont-run-after-extracting), but nothing has changed.*

Specifications:
OS: Windows XP Professional SP3 2002
RAM: 1.94 GB (Physical Address Extension) 
Processor: Intel Core 2 Duo CPU L9400 @ 1.86 GHz

Here is the bootstrapper log:

Beginning of the log. Start Time: 8/13/2017 10:17:31 PM

Here, also is the vs community log:

[8/13/2017, 22:29:17] === Logging started: 2017/08/13 22:29:17 ===
[8/13/2017, 22:29:17] Executable: C:\Documents and Settings\mbryant\My Documents\Downloads\vs_community__1386048972.1502586709.exe v15.0.26430.16
[8/13/2017, 22:29:17] --- logging level: standard ---
[8/13/2017, 22:29:17] Directory 'C:\DOCUME~1\mbryant\LOCALS~1\Temp\bffc0c68a6fdffa54c31cb757f56bada\' has been selected for file extraction
[8/13/2017, 22:29:17] Extracting files to: C:\DOCUME~1\mbryant\LOCALS~1\Temp\bffc0c68a6fdffa54c31cb757f56bada\
[8/13/2017, 22:29:17] Extraction took 438 milliseconds
[8/13/2017, 22:29:17] Executing extracted package: 'vs_bootstrapper_d15\vs_setup_bootstrapper.exe ' with commandline ' '
[8/13/2017, 22:29:19] The entire Box execution exiting with result code: 0x0
[8/13/2017, 22:29:19] Launched extracted application exiting with result code: 0x1389
[8/13/2017, 22:29:19] === Logging stopped: 2017/08/13 22:29:19 ===

If anyone could help me, it would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

According to the Visual Studio 2017 Requirements page, Windows XP is not supported:

[Link here](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/productinfo/vs2017-system-requirements-vs)