# Visual studio 2017 error loading rule set file

Tags: c++, visual-studio, ide, visual-studio-2017, loading

When I try to view the properties dialog of any project VS2017 spits out a bunch of errors.

```
"An error occurred while loading the rule set file 'C:/Program 
Files(x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\Team Tools\Static Analysis 
Tools\Rule Sets\AllRules.ruleset'."

..\BasicCorrectnessRules.ruleset'.
..\DesignGuidelinesRules.ruleset'.
..\ExtendedCorrectnessRules.ruleset'.
..\ExtendedDesignGuidelinesRules.ruleset.'
..\GlobalizationRules.ruleset'.
..\ManagedMinimumRules.ruleset'.
..\MinimumRecommendedRules.ruleset'.
..\MixedMinimumRules.ruleset'.
..\MixedReccommendedRules.ruleset'.
..\NativeMinimumRules.ruleset'.
..\NativeReccommendedRules.ruleset'.
..\SecurityRules.ruleset'.
```

I don't know why this started happening, I didn't change anything in the install directory. All of those files are there in the directory, not sure why they are causing errors. Anyone know the cause?

Answer (score 0):

Bottom line: I had the same problem.  I had to do a repair install of Visual Studio 2017 to make this work properly.  I tried just upgrading to Version 15.4.5 (from 15.4.4), but it didn't resolve the problem.

The problem didn't track the solution being used. I have two computers - one worked with the solution, the other failed with identical files.  I copied the 'rules' files from the working computer to the failed one - no joy.  On the working computer, I updated VS successfully (to 15.4.5), but on the failing computer I couldn't get the update to work (see [Visual studio 2017 installer won't run after extracting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43025670/visual-studio-2017-installer-wont-run-after-extracting/47600749#47600749)).  Once I resolved the problem noted in the other link and updated to 15.4.5, I still had to do a 'repair install' (from Add/Remove Programs) to completely resolve the problem.