# Visual Studio 2017 installer won't run after extracting to temp

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

I have Windows 10 64 bit, but Visual Studio Community 2017 won't run after extracting to the temp.

The install log in appdata/local/temp/ is as follow:

```
Beginning of the log. Start Time: 18/07/2018 10:37:34
VisualStudio Bootstrapper:18/07/2018 10:37:34: Current Optin root path does not exists
VisualStudio Bootstrapper:18/07/2018 10:37:35: Commandline arguments = --env,_SFX_CAB_EXE_PACKAGE:C:\Users\Home\Desktop\vs_community__451262325.1531901547.exe _SFX_CAB_EXE_ORIGINALWORKINGDIR:C:\Users\Home\Desktop
VisualStudio Bootstrapper:18/07/2018 10:37:35: Parent process name = vs_community__451262325.1531901547
VisualStudio Bootstrapper:18/07/2018 10:37:35: Parent process product version = 15.7.27703.2042
VisualStudio Bootstrapper:18/07/2018 10:37:35: CampaignId = 451262325.1531901547
VisualStudio Bootstrapper:18/07/2018 10:37:35: loading config settings: -update --update --layout -offline --offline --locale --layout --originalworkingdir --installLayoutPath --env
VisualStudio Bootstrapper:18/07/2018 10:37:35: DownloadURL = https://aka.ms/vs/15/release/installer
VisualStudio Bootstrapper:18/07/2018 10:37:35: InstallLocation = C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Installer
VisualStudio Bootstrapper:18/07/2018 10:37:35: OfflineFilePath = 
VisualStudio Bootstrapper:18/07/2018 10:37:35: LayoutLocation = 
VisualStudio Bootstrapper:18/07/2018 10:37:35: ExecutableArguments = /finalizeInstall install --in "C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\VisualStudio\Packages\_bootstrapper\vs_setup_bootstrapper_201807181037350504.json" --locale it-IT --activityId "9e16c778-7bcb-41c1-90c2-f88768d9bf9f" --campaign "451262325.1531901547"
VisualStudio Bootstrapper:18/07/2018 10:37:35: OSVersion = Microsoft Windows NT 10.0.17134.0
VisualStudio Bootstrapper:18/07/2018 10:37:35: Starting to detect the existing VS and .Net...
VisualStudio Bootstrapper:18/07/2018 10:37:35: Finished detecting the existing VS and .Net
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Visual studio 2017 installer won't run after extracting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43025670/visual-studio-2017-installer-wont-run-after-extracting)

Comment: no, is a different error

Comment: Have you tried the various solutions presented in the answers? (But maybe not the reinstall Windows one yet.)

Comment: yes, but not work

Comment: Is there anything in the Windows event logs that gives a hint as to what might be going wrong? Otherwise, the fastest course of action at this point is likely to be backup the computer, reinstall Windows, and try again.